# Difference between Taylor polynomial of $f(r)=(1+\frac{a^2-2ay}{r^2})^{-3/2}$ at $r=m$ as $m\to \infty$ and the function $(1+s)^{-3/2}$ at $s=0$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, maple, linear-approximation

Consider the expression

$$E(x,y)=\frac{x\hat{i}+(y-a)\hat{j}}{(x^2+(y-a)^2)^{3/2}}\tag{1}$$

where $r^2=x^2+y^2$. I'd like to investigate what happens when $r>>a$.

Let's consider the factor involving just the denominator

$$(x^2+(y-a)^2)^{-3/2}$$

$$=(x^2+y^2-2ay+a^2)^{-3/2}$$

$$=\left [ (x^2+y^2)(1+\frac{a^2-2ay}{x^2+y^2})\right ]^{-3/2}$$

$$=r^{-3}\left ( 1+ \frac{a^2-2ay}{r^2} \right )^{-3/2}\tag{2}$$

Let $s(r)=\frac{a^2-2ay}{r^2}$ and let $f(x)=(1+x)^{-3/2}$.

Then $f(s(r))=\left ( 1+ \frac{a^2-2ay}{r^2} \right )^{-3/2}\tag{3}$

Since $s\to 0$ as $r\to \infty$, apparently we can use a Taylor approximation to $f(x)$ near $0$ to find out what happens to (3) as $r\to\infty$.

$$P_{1,f,0}=1-\frac{3}{2}s\tag{4}$$

This is a linear approximation to $f$ near $x=0$. When $r\to\infty$ and $s\to 0$, $f(s(r))\approx 1-\frac{3}{2}s$.

Which means that when $r\to\infty$ the expression in (2) is approximately

$$r^{-3}(1-\frac{3}{2}s)$$

$$=r^{-3}\left (1-\frac{3}{2}\frac{a^2-2ay}{r^2}\right )\tag{5}$$

which we can sub into (1) to reach the desired expression for $E$ when $r>>a$.

**What is the theorem or theorems that justify this type of calculation when we have a function composition?**

**What do I have to study to learn more about this specific topic of using Taylor approximations like they do in physics?**

I recall from studying Taylor polynomials and Taylor's Theorem a formula for computing the Taylor polynomial of a function composition. The expression in  (3) is a function composition.

If we apply the formula

$$P_{n,a,f\circ s}=\left [ P_{n,s(m),f}\circ P_{n,m,s} \right ]_n$$

where the $[]$ operator means truncation of terms that are of degree $\leq n$, then we reach the second-to-last result seen in the following Maple session (which includes all the calculations mentioned above):

[image]

Equation (12) above is the first-order Taylor polynomial of the function composition in (3). But it seems like this result isn't as useful as the previous one obtained in (5).

The variable $m$ in (12) represents the value about which we computed the Taylor polynomial of the function composition.

**Is there some useful way to relate this calculation with the one that led to (5)?**

Comment: $s(r)$ seems to not be well defined since it depends on $y$ ($r^2=x^2+y^2$)

Comment: @OliverDíaz the calculations above come straight from lecture notes to an MIT OCW course, 8.02 Electromagnetism. I get the feeling that when applying many calculus concepts in practice, physicists do things and then mathematicians make observations like the one you just did. For someone trying to figure it out it is quite difficult. The calculations I used are from: https://openlearninglibrary.mit.edu/courses/course-v1:MITx+8.02.1x+1T2019/pdfbook/0/